# 3.2 upgrade, drafts table error

Tags: plugins, updating

When I try to upgrade to 3.2 on my site I get an error saying the drafts table already exists.  Does anyone know of any plugins that use such a table?  I'm trying to sort out what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you didn't completely roll the database back to 3.1 before re-trying the update. That table probably got created the *first* time you tried to update to 3.2.

Make sure the database is wiped 100% clean before rolling back to your 3.1 database. Then try updating again.

Comment: That'll be hard to do with a prod database, but I'll see what I can do with it.  Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Do you have a copy of the database from before your first attempt?